# Cannot identify the correct COSMOS DB SQL SELECT syntax to check if coordinates (Point) are within a Polygon

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, geojson, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I m developing an app that uses Cosmos DB SQL. The intention is to identify if a potential construction site is within various restricted zones, such as national parks and sites of special scientific interest. This information is very useful in obtaining all the appropriate planning permissions.

I have created a container named 'geodata' containing 15 documents that I imported using data from a Geojson file provided by the UK National Parks. I have confirmed that all the polygons are valid using a ST_ISVALIDDETAILED SQL statement. I have also checked that the coordinates are anti-clockwise. A few documents contain MultiPolygons. The Geospatial Configuration of the container is 'Geography'.

I am using the Azure Cosmos Data Explorer to identify the correct format of a SELECT statement to identify if given coordinates (Point) are within any of the polygons within the 15 documents.

```
SELECT c.properties.npark18nm 
FROM c
WHERE ST_WITHIN({"type": "Point", "coordinates":[-3.139638969259495,54.595188276959284]}, c.geometry)
```

The embedded coordinates are within a National Park, in this case, the Lake District in the UK (it also happens to be my favourite coffee haunt).

'c.geometry' is the JSON field within the documents.

```
"type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "objectid": 3,
        "npark18cd": "E26000004",
        "npark18nm": "Northumberland National Park",
        "npark18nmw": " ",
        "bng_e": 385044,
        "bng_n": 600169,
        "long": -2.2370801,
        "lat": 55.29539871,
        "st_areashape": 1050982397.6985701,
        "st_lengthshape": 339810.592994494
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [
                    -2.182235310191206,
                    55.586659699934806
                ],
                [
                    -2.183754259805564,
                    55.58706479201416
                ], ......
```

Link to the full document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yul6ft2rweod75s/lakedistrictnationlpark.json?dl=0

I have not been able to format the SELECT query to return the name of the park successfully.

Can you help me?

Is what I want to achieve possible?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what error you are getting. And you have misspelt "c.geometry".

This should work

```
SELECT c.properties.npark18nm 
FROM c
WHERE ST_WITHIN({"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-3.139638969259495,54.595188276959284]}, c.geometry)
```

When running the query with your sample document, I was able to get the correct response(see image).[image]
So this particular document is fine and the query in your question works too. Can you recheck your query on the explorer again? Also, are you referring to the incorrect database/collection by any chance?
Maybe a full screen shot of cosmos data explorer showing the dbs/collections, your query and response will also help.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting the the spelling mistake, but it was only in this post I made the error, in Data Explorer it was spelt correctly.

Comment: The query appears run OK, but returns no rows. Given that the Point is within one the records, I would have expected it to return one row.

Comment: Can you please edit the question with the full document so we can also check ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. Thank you for taking the time to look at this problem.

Comment: Thank you Anupam for taking the time to look into my issue. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem. Not by altering the SQL statement but by deleting the container the data was held in, recreating it and reloading the data.

The SQL statement now produces the expected results.